# MediaWiki API - Using new line for bullet points

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm having trouble trying to do bullet points using the MediaWiki API, I can't work out how to get it to do the new line, everything ends up on the same line.

I've tried using

```
$maps[] = "* " . $mapName . "<br/>";
$maps[] = "* " . $mapName . "\n";
$maps[] = "* " . $mapName . "\r\n";
```

None of which work

I'm updating the wiki using

```
$endPoint = "URL";

$params4 = [
    "action" => "edit",
    "title" => $title,
    "text" => $content,
    "token" => $csrf_Token,
    "format" => "json"
];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endPoint );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $params4 ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt" );

$output = curl_exec( $ch );

curl_close( $ch );
```

Comment: If you are passing this as a GET parameter, you should encode the newline appropriately (`%0D%0A`). Alternatively, you could send the text as a POST parameter (MediaWiki will treat them equally).

Comment: I've added the code I'm using to update the wiki to the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using

```
$maps[] = "* [[" . $mapName . "]]<br/>%0D%0A";
```